# Converting NTX data to DXF/SHP

Tags: shapefile, convert

I've inherited some old CARIS GIS data (NTX format) and am needing to convert it into something usable while ensuring that all attributes remain intact. I do know of the NTXShape application (http://ntxshape.sourceforge.net/) but have gotten little success with that, primarily because a working copy of ArcView 3.x is rare as hen's teeth and Windows 7/8 doesn't seem to like the command line application.

Are there any other applications (preferably opensource) that may be able to undertake the conversion?

Comment: The first version of ArcMap was 8.0 so I suspect you mean ArcView 3.x. Updating your question is easy using the **edit** button beneath it.

Comment: Are you getting error messages with the command line? Are you running the dos window/command prompt window as an administrator? What about setting the OS compatibility on the executable?

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to CARIS GIS software you could use the BUILEDIT command to convert the NTX files to CARIS files and then use REROAUTO to convert the CARIS files to AutoCAD DXF (v12).

The NTX will have very few attributes because the Caris format does not include an attribute table.  All Attributes were handled by an external database.  However, the Caris file will include:

- Feature code (FC) - 12 alpha-numeric characters - identifies type of feature (road, ditch, stream, building, etc
- User number (UN) - numeric (I can't recall the limits) - akin to a layer number
- Theme number (TH) - numeric (I can't recall the limits) - again akin to a layer number but usually reserved for layers with topology
- Source ID - 12 alpha-numeric characters - codes to identify the source of the feature